# Upgrade runtime options for AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have a Lambda function which runs currently on Python 3.9.
Now I'm trying to upgrade the runtime to python 3.11.
So I updated my aws cli and python to the newest version.

```
aws --version` is `aws-cli/2.13.17 Python/3.11.5 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/of
```

But I'm getting this error here:

> Configuration error at 'provider.runtime': must be equal to one of the allowed values [dotnet6, go1.x, java17, java11, java8, java8.al2, nodejs14.x, nodejs16.x, nodejs18.x, provided, provided.al2, python3.7, python3.8, python3.9, python3.10, ruby2.7]

I'm searching for a solution but I always geet this error when trying to change dependencies or anything else.
Maybe someone can help, thanks in advance :)

I'm deploying my Lambda via Serverless, this is my serverless.yaml:

```
service: name

frameworkVersion: '3'
configValidationMode: error

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  profile:
    dev: dev
    prod: prod 
  deploymentBucket:
    dev: bucket-dev
    prod: bucket-prod
  environment: ${self:custom.environments.${self:custom.stage}, self:custom.environments.dev}
  environments: ${file(environment-definition.yaml)}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.11
  region: eu-central-1
  stage: dev
  profile: ${self:custom.profile.${self:custom.stage}}
  deploymentMethod: direct
  deploymentBucket:
    name: ${self:custom.deploymentBucket.${self:custom.stage}}

functions:
  lambda_handler:
    handler: handler.lambda_handler
    timeout: 300
    environment: ${self:custom.environment.envVars}
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          schedule: cron(0 0 ? * 4#1 *) 

          
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - __pycache__

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-better-credentials
```

Comment: it is not in the list of supported version, so you can update it

Comment: But python 3.11 should be possible https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html

Comment: paper is very patient, you need to wait till it is supported

Comment: But it is already supported! Look at the aws documentation link I added. 
In the aws console I can select this runtime, but in my local serverless lambda I can just select the runtime until 3.10

Comment: Amazon lag with the implementation, even when it is written on a webpage, that was here shown multiple times already

Comment: Where are you setting `provider.runtime`? Are you deploying your Lambda function via the AWS CLI tool, or via some other tool like Terraform, CloudFormation, etc? Please edit your question to show what specific thing you are doing when you get that error message.

Comment: my serverless.yaml is added

Answer (score 1):

I had to update my serverless local version. After that python 3.11 was available.
Thanks for your time :)